# Unable to logout in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, logout

I've edited my `.htaccess` file, so that pages of the form `mydomain.com/events.php?slug=1234` become `mydomain.com/events/1234`.

Following are the codes from `events.php`:

My logout code is below inside `<body>`:

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){?>
     <a href="?<?php echo $url; ?>&logout" ><button>Log Out</button></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

And, in the starting of the page, I have:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require_once('13/functions/db.php');
session_name('tryst1');
session_set_cookie_params(3*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$useremail = $_SESSION['email'];
$username = $_SESSION['name'];
    $slug = $_GET['slug'];
    $url="http://mydomain.com/events/".$slug."/";
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}
```

But, I'm unable to logout and the URL shown is: `http://www.mydomain.com/events/1234/?http://domain.com/events/1234/&logout`

Need help. What am I doing wrong?

The starting `php` code of my `events.php` is :: http://dpaste.com/915935/

My `.htaccess` file is at:: http://dpaste.com/915939/

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: Yes. I chose a random name. The logout worked when I didn't edit the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: `$url` must be wrong when you embed it into the logout link. what do you get when you hover the most over the link in you browser? probably that "wrong" url. check where $url is being built.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: So, should I remove the whole `session_name('tryst1');` part? I don't want to make the other people logout.

Comment: @xan nevermind, I was thinking about session_id. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your link is

```
href="?http://mydomain.com/events/".$slug."/&logout"
```

Do you see the error? Especially `?` at beginning? Fix it to:

```
href="<?php echo $url; ?>?logout"
```

Comment: Still I'm not able to logout. I've removed the `session_name` line. After logging out, URL becomes: `http://www.mydomain.com/events.php?slug=1234`, and I'm still logged in.

Comment: So you have another problem somewhere else. I don't see `events.php` anywhere in your question except htaccess

Comment: btw `<a href=".."><button></button></a>` is not valid HTML

Comment: `<button>` ,ay submit your form. And as I said you are not allowed to put `<button>` between `<a></a>`

Comment: There is no `form`. Just a `<button>` element. I tried removing the `<button>` part. Still the same problem.

Comment: Still problem is somewhere else. Can't help you without full code

Comment: Why did you downvote the question? You can view the starting php code of my events.php file here: http://dpaste.com/915935/

Comment: try to replace `[L,NC]` to `[L,NC,QSA]`. And there is no need to use `RewriteEngine On` more than once

Comment: On logging out, the URL is still : `http://www.mydomain.com/events.php?slug=1234`